# Pattern matching union type from thrift-generated scala

Tags: scala, thrift

Imagine a union in thrift like:

```
union MyUnion {
  1. bool myBool
  2. i64 myLong
  3. double myDouble
}(persisted='true')
```

What I'd like to do is something like this in Scala:

```
case class MyClass(
  myString: String,
  myUnionType: ???
)
```

Then, I'd like to instantiate this class like:

```
import ...{thriftscala => thrift}

val myClass = MyClass("cool", thrift.MyUnion.MyBool)
val myOtherClass = MyClass("wow", thrift.MyUnion.MyLong)
```

Note that I am not instantiating `MyBool` or `MyLong`, I just want to pass them as "types". I.e., I am not doing:

```
val myClass = MyClass("cool", thrift.MyUnion.MyBool(_))
```

I'm curious if there is a way to do this using the thrift-generated Scala.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [ADT](http://tpolecat.github.io/presentations/algebraic_types.html#1) like this :

```
scala> sealed trait MyUnion
defined trait
```

MyUnion

This is your base class and then extends with case object :

```
scala> case object  MyBool extends MyUnion
defined object MyBool

scala> case object MyDouble extends MyUnion
defined object MyDouble

scala> case object MyLong extends MyUnion
defined object MyLong

scala> case class MyClass(str : String, union : MyUnion)
defined class MyClass
```

How use it :

```
scala> MyClass("cool", MyBool)
res0: MyClass = MyClass(cool,MyBool)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. This is actually the way I'm currently handling it. The problem, however, is that now, in order to add a new "type" to MyBool, one needs to add it to both thrift *and* Scala. What I'm trying to do is leverage the thrift-generated Scala so I only have to add the type to the thrift file, without needing to maintain a separate trait.

Comment: There isn't _really_ a way to do this because of the way the code is generated. You could implement a trait as @alifirat suggested, or you could implement a type class to handle union values for you. Either way though, you're going to have to implement _something_ if you change your thrift unions.